# Vapor 4 case insensitive query

Tags: swift, fluent, vapor, vapor-fluent

In Vapor 3 you could use `filter` method with a SQLiteBinaryOperator, so you could create a query with a like operator. I'm trying to do the exact same thing in Vapor 4 but couldn't find anything for that.
Here's my code

Vapor 4

```
func queryUserMovies(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<[Users]> {
    let title = req.parameters.get("title")!
    return Movies.query(on: req.db).filter(\.$title == title).first().unwrap(or:Abort(.notFound, reason: "There's no movie")).flatMap{ movie in
        return movie.$users.query(on: req.db).all()
    }
}
```

Vapor 3

```
func queryUserMovies(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<[Users]> {
    guard let movie = req.query[String.self, at: "movie"] else {
        throw Abort(.badRequest, reason: "Not such movie")
    }
    return Movies.query(on: req).filter(\.title, .like, movie).first().unwrap(or:Abort(.notFound, reason: "There's no movie")).flatMap{ movie in
        return movie.users.query(on: req).all()
    }
}
```

Is there anything similar in Vapor 4 or do I need to perform a raw query in SQL?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The equivalent in Vapor 4 is:

```swift
func queryUserMovies(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<[Users]> {
    let title = try req.query.get(String.self, at: "title")
    return Movies.query(on: req.db)
        .filter(\.$title, .custom("ilike"), title)
        .first()
        .unwrap(or:Abort(.notFound, reason: "There's no movie"))
        .flatMap{ movie in
            return movie.$users.query(on: req.db).all()
    }
}
```

You can even perform a wider search to find anything containing that title:

```swift
.filter(\.$title, .custom("ilike"), "%\(title)%")
```

Comment: Is this save to use with a user entered title, e.g. preventing SQL injection?

Comment: Yes, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63688526/1823705) as to why

Comment: Use `.custom("like")` on SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue, but with one more obstacle!

The setup is a *Machine* relation joined with a *Category* relation and I wanted to search for occurrences of one or more search-terms in the *Machine.name* and *Category.name* with one expression.

(Both the *Machine* and the *Category* relations have a *name* attribute.)

*search* is of the Type *[String.SubSequence]*, so we can iterate over multiple search-term keywords, which must all be present somewhere in the names.

My solution was:

```
return Machine
  .query(on: req.db)
  .join(Category.self, on: \Category.$id == \Machine.$category.$id)
  // For each search-term the must be at least one fit with Machine.name and/or Category.name
  .group(.and) {
    var result = $0
    for term in search.map({ "%\(String($0))%" }) {
      // One or both must fit the search-term ...
      result = result.group(.or) {
        $0
          // Does the Machine name fit?
          .filter(\Machine.$name, .custom("ilike"), term)
          // Does the Category.path name fit?
          .filter(
            DatabaseQuery.Field.path(
              Category.path(for: \Category.$name),
              schema: Category.schema
            ),
            DatabaseQuery.Filter.Method.custom("ilike"),
            DatabaseQuery.Value.bind(term)
          )
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see there are two *.group(...)* functions. The outer group (*.or*) says "for each search-term there must be one fitting inner group rule" and the inner group (*.or*) says "there must be at lease a fitting Machine.name or Category.name".

Since *.custom("ilike")* is not supported by the "joined-relation-filter" I used the workaround I found [here](https://github.com/vapor/fluent-kit/issues/310).

Even tough the question may already be answered, I spend some time figuring this out and thought I could share it here.

Answer (score 1):

There is the contains operator, ~~, that can be used for this:

```
Movie.query(on: req).filter(\.$title ~~ movie)
```

It is case-insensitive.

Comment: I'm using `~~` but it's *not* case-insensitive for me.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth, I'm using MySQL, could it be the underlying database? I haven't been able to find the implementation in Fluent yet. Just checked my code and it doesn't do any folding, etc. but is working.

Comment: Perhaps yeah, I'm using PostgreSQL. I've found the Vapor 3.0.0 version of 0xTim's answer to work for me, while this operator didn't, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do case-insensitive ordering, you can do this:

```
Movie.query(on: req).sort(.custom("lower(title)"))
```